# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{e^{-n}n^{i}}{i!}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, poisson-distribution

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{e^{-n}n^{i}}{i!}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$

**Tried:**
here suppose N is poission distribution with parameter n
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} P(N\geq i) $
$= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}(P(N=i)+P(N>i) + P(N<i)-P(N<i)) $
$= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}(P(N= i)+P(i<N<i)-P(N<i)$
$= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}(P(N= i)-P(N<i)$ ;  $(P(i<N<i)=0)$
$=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(P(N= i)-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(N<i)$
$=1-\frac{1}{2}$ $=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. You wanted $P(N \leq i)$. If you imitated your first step and then carried through the remaining steps correctly, you would arrive at $1-P(N> i)$, which is useless. Anyway, your expression is $P(X_n \leq n)$ where $n$ has the Poisson(n) distribution. There is a famous way to approximate the Poisson(n) distribution for large $n$...

Comment: I am not getting ...

Comment: The Poisson(n) distribution can be realized by summing n independent, identically distributed Poisson(1) variables. This "infinite divisibility" property is one of the basic properties of the Poisson distribution (along with several other famous distributions...)

Comment: By the law of large numbers, the probability that a limit Poisson distribution is less than its mean value is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Actually, it's the central limit theorem, not the law of large numbers. The weak law of large numbers only tells you that $P((1-\varepsilon)n \leq X_n \leq (1+\varepsilon)n)$ goes to $1$ for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$. It doesn't say how $P((1-\varepsilon)n \leq X_n < n)$ compares to $P(n < X_n \leq (1+\varepsilon)n$.

Comment: @Ian: I apologize, you're right. Anyway, I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, it is, it's not that hard to find it, but I'd like to see Ashutosh think about it a bit. With some thought, there is some very interesting structure here in the connection between the binomial, Poisson, and normal distributions. Being told the detailed answer makes it seem like "just another problem" with no real meaning.